# Restore Eclipse Welcome page via plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, menubar

I have got a customized eclipse installation which doesn't contain `Help -> Welcome` option in it. Some plugin have hidden it from the menu.

Is there a way that I can get that option back by overriding some plugin or contribute to menu using `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point?

So far I have tried following by extending `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` to make all menu's visible but this is effective for only the menus that are already there.

```
@Override
public void postWindowOpen() { 
    IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IContributionItem[] items = ((WorkbenchWindow)workbenchWindow).getMenuBarManager().getItems();
    for (IContributionItem item : items) {
            item.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

The most likely plugin seems to be `org.eclipse.ui.workbench`

Comment: Are you sure the _Welcome_ page is [correctly enabled in your RCP product](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro_universal_defaults.htm)? What do you mean by _"Some plugin have hidden it from the menu"_? What plugin has hidden the _Help > Welcome_ menu item?

Comment: When I click Help button, I don't see Welcome option in the submenu. I not sure which plugin in the installation have hidden this. I am looking at ways to again make is visible.

Comment: The plugin ```org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal``` is their in the eclipse installation which normally is the base plugin for Universal Welcome.

Comment: What make you believe it's hidden by a plugin and not by e.g. a misconfiguration of the product (e.g. broken `introData.xml`, something in the `plugin_customization.ini` file, etc.)?

Comment: I have gone through ```introData.xml``` and ```plugin_customization.ini``` files are they are fine. The only thing I changed was setting the value of following property to true: ```org.eclipse.ui/showIntro=false```. But this has nothing to do with the hiding of Welcome page.

Comment: Lets assume that the Welcome page is intentionally hidden by some plugin. So, I am looking to restore it.

Comment: If your assumption is true, the _Welcome_ page can still be opened via Ctrl+3, typing `welcome` and hitting Enter. Can you confirm that this is true?

Comment: Yes, I can see the welcome page this way.

Comment: Is it in _Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective..._ in the tab _Menu Visibility_?

Comment: No, Welcome options isn't there in the Customize perspective.

Comment: Mhh, maybe just the _Welcome_ page (internally also called _intro_) is not [set for the product](https://git.eclipse.org/c/gerrit/platform/eclipse.platform.git/tree/platform/org.eclipse.platform/plugin.xml?id=be35f541d649b413023e40c3f2fcbeee6e762d12#n65) or the product ID has changed. Otherwise, adding as regular menu item (the command ID is `org.eclipse.ui.help.quickStartAction`) or via so-called action set might work.

Comment: @howlger How can I see that which product ID is being used?

Comment: The default product ID is in the `configuration/config.ini` file as `eclipse.product=<product ID>` (which can be overridden in the `eclipse.ini` (or your RCP `<app name>.ini`) or on the command line via [`-product <product ID>`](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a detailed debugging, there was a plugin in my installation which was using wrong `productID` in the `org.eclipse.ui.intro` extension, hence welcome page option was not visible.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.intro">
      <introProductBinding
            introId="org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal"
            productId="com.xyz.ide">
      </introProductBinding>
   </extension>
```